# Helm not using values.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I downloaded the latest [values.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/alertmanager/values.yaml) and updated config block and ran the command `helm upgrade alertmanager prometheus-community/alertmanager --values values.yaml` but the alertmanager-0 pod config file isn't changing at all.

`values.yaml partial content:`

```
config:
  global:
    # slack_api_url: ''

  templates:
    - '/etc/alertmanager/*.tmpl'

  receivers:
    - name: default-receiver
      email_configs:
      - to: test@gmail.com
        from: test@gmail.com
        smarthost: postfix.test-internal:25
      # slack_configs:
      #  - channel: '@you'
      #    send_resolved: true

  route:
    group_wait: 10s
    group_interval: 5m
    receiver: default-receiver
    repeat_interval: 3h
```

When I check the `alertmanager.yml` it still has the default content:

```
kubectl exec -it alertmanager-0 cat /etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml

global: {}
receivers:
- name: default-receiver
route:
  group_interval: 5m
  group_wait: 10s
  receiver: default-receiver
  repeat_interval: 3h
templates:
- /etc/alertmanager/*.tmpl
```

Answer (score 1):

If your config didn't change, you are probably not injecting the values correctly (wrong indentation or node).

In order to figure out how the values are executed, use `helm template alertmanager -f values.yaml > out.yaml` which will show you how the end manifsets get templated.

In order to figure out where you should inject the values, you can untar the chart's dependency in the `charts` directory and check the template under `templates/<chart-name>/<manifest-name>yaml` (example: `charts/alertmanager/templates/statefulset.yaml`).

Finally, you can run `helm upgrade alertmanager prometheus-community/alertmanager --values values.yaml --debug --dry-run > dry-run.yaml` to see how the values get computed. With this you can see where your values are injected.

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to figure this out also.

I can see from the alertmanager kube secrets that there are two with one appended with "-generated".

This "-generated" secret is the one which is mounted into the pods into /etc/alertmanager/config (alertmanager.yaml) how ever the problem is that when I updated the values.yaml file on my machine, apply an upgrade then the "-generated" secret has the original default values and the one without the "-generated" has the correct new values.

I'm sure there must be a reason it's done this way but can't figure out the correct way of working with these. I would think that when you change the values in the values.yaml that those should be the ones actively applied to the config running in the alertmanager pod.

Anyone with more info on this would be great to know the answer.

Comment: Welcome Mason. This answer reads more like a question. I suggest creating a new question with these details in it.